# How to delete the second instance of a value in a row in R

Tags: r

I have data that looks like the data below. I want to delete the second time a value is seen. Values are defined as being between the vertical bars (e.g. "|").

```
row1 <- "A|C|A|B|B|C"
row2 <- "C|C|B|A|A|B"
df <- rbind(row1,row2)
```

My goal is that the first row is A|C|B and the second row is C|B|A. Assume I actually have 10 letters rather than just 3. All values are in the row only twice. I don't even know how to start with this problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is a string operation, not a frame operation, so `dplyr` is the wrong hammer to use on this nail.
2. Is there a reason you are keeping this as a string, vice breaking it into individual values? Perhaps not critical at the moment ...

```r
vec <- c("A|C|A|B|B|C", "C|C|B|A|A|B")
strsplit(vec, "\\|")
# [[1]]
# [1] "A" "C" "A" "B" "B" "C"
# [[2]]
# [1] "C" "C" "B" "A" "A" "B"
sapply(strsplit(vec, "\\|"), function(v) paste(unique(v), collapse = "|"))
# [1] "A|C|B" "C|B|A"
```